# ¿como guardar en local storage de select?

Tags: javascript, html

Hola como estan? como puedo guardar el valor de select con local Storage, que se vea reflejado en select y obtener el ultimo valor seleccionado?

**

```
<select onchange="valor(this)" name="select" id="mi-select">
  <option value="1">0</option> 
  <option value="2">1</option>
  <option value="3">2</option>
  <option value="Seleccionar" disabled selected>Select a Midi Out!</option>
</select>
<script><!--
//referenciamos el select
var miSelect = document.getElementById("mi-select");
//evento para cuando cambia el valor del select
miSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
  //obtenemos el texto y el valor que se seleccionaron
  var textoSeleccionado = miSelect.options[miSelect.selectedIndex].text,
      valorSeleccionado = miSelect.options[miSelect.selectedIndex].value;
     
});
function valor() {
 
valorSeleccionado = miSelect.options[miSelect.selectedIndex].value
}
```

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he probado este JS y me funciono perfecto.
Asi quedaria tu codigo:

```
<select onchange="valor(this)" name="select" id="mi-select">
  <option value="1">0</option> 
  <option value="2">1</option>
  <option value="3">2</option>
  <option value="Seleccionar" disabled selected>Select a Midi Out!</option>
</select>
```

Y el JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mi-select').change(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('ejemplo', this.value);
    });
    if(localStorage.getItem('ejemplo')){
        $('#mi-select').val(localStorage.getItem('ejemplo'));
    }
});
```

[Y aca el JSFiddle por si quieres verlo en vivo:](https://jsfiddle.net/yfgw7uek/1/)

Espero haberte ayudado, intenta ser un poco mas especifico a la proxima.